# PHP indirect object access efficiency

Tags: php, performance, variables, memory

I'd like to know whether its more efficient to access a class variable directly instead of indirectly, ie via a class method.

For example I have the following (pseudo)code:

```
class foo {

    private $some_object;    

    public function __construct(){

        $this->some_object = new someObject();    
    }

    public function getSomeObject(){

        return $this->some_object;    
    }

} //end of class foo
```

The first access method uses the object stored and directly accesses the object stored

```
$f            = new foo();
$storedObject = $f->getSomeObject();

for (loop 10 times) {

    print $storedObject->getSomeProperty();

}
```

The second method accesses the `$f->some_object` via the `getSomeObject()` method

```
$f            = new foo();

for(loop 10 times){

    print $f->getSomeObject()->getSomeProperty();

}
```

I know PHP returns objects by reference but method 2, looks more inefficient to me; or are they both the same?

Comment: The first is faster, but if you'll notice the difference I have to say congrats, you've probably got the second Facebook running (ie. don't bother with such optimizations, do profiling and optimize only when you've got performance problems).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense from a clean coding perspective. It will also save me the headache of keeping track of the extra variable created

Answer (score 0):

In PHP objects are returned by value. The value represents the object then (object identifier value).

Next to that it's perfectly okay to store a return value of a function and use it 10 times instead calling the function 10 times and use the return value directly.

Do what makes more sense with your code, normally code is more easy to read if you have one variable name instead of reading one variable name and a function name. But it's your choice.